# Regexp argument to readlines

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to pass in `/\!|\.|\?/` to the separator argument for `readlines`. It seems it's not possible. Or is it?

`f.readlines(/\!|\.|\?/)`

I know the alternative is to use `read` and `split`, which accepts Regexp, but I want to know if this is also possible with `readlines`

Answer (score 2):

[`IO#readlines`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines) expects a string, not a regular expression. But the desired behaviour might be easily achieved with `read` + `split` since according to the documentation `readlines` “reads the entire file”:

```
f.read.split /\!|\.|\?/
```

Please also read the valuable comment by @tom-lord with a significant improvement suggestion.

Comment: I would also suggest using a slightly more legible regex: `/[!.?]/`